# O Git Bash não está conseguindo abrir uma conexão com o meu agente de autenticação

Tags: git, windows, github

Estou tentando configurar o meu github no windows pelo git bash com a ajuda desse blog: http://gabsferreira.com/instalando-o-git-e-configurando-github/, mas o git bash não consegue uma conexão com o meu agente de autenticação.
Eu faço como pedido na parte "2- Agora, precisamos adicionar a chave que criamos ao ssh-agent. Primeiro, vamos ativa-lo:" e aparece:[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Logo em seguida faço o que é pedido na parte "Em seguida, vamos adicionar a chave que geramos ao ssh-agent:" e aparece:[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Sou muito iniciante no git bash e estou perdida. Uma mãozinha?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ola,

no proprio post achei um problema parecido com o seu e a reposta da pessoa foi:

> exec ssh-agent bash, executa isso e depois refaz o ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa.

Pode ser que ajude.[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Muito obrigada, não tinha visto mesmo!